# Only file owner can change Windows Read-Only attribute thru Samba

Tags: server, permissions, samba

Ubuntu Server 14.04, files shared through Samba.  In Windows 7, only the file owner has privileges to change to Windows read-only attribute.  I would like the group to be able to set and unset that attribute.  I tried "dos filemode" in the samba.conf, but that allowed a non-owner to set the read-only attribute, but then they could not unset it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

File permissions are decided by the 'create mask' setting in your smb.conf file.

So 'create mask = 0755' will mean a file with permissions of rwxr-xr-x while 'create mask = 0775' will mean rwxrwxr-x

Comment: I do not have any problems with the normal permissions.  I have individual files that the Windows group users want to set or un-set the "read only" attribute in Windows.  Currently the group has read and write permissions, but only the file owner can change the read only attribute through the Windows file properties.

Comment: Hmm... OK! Not something I've ever tried but I DO know that linux system permissions take precedence over samba permissions. Check out  http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-set-permissions-to-samba-shares.html Might also be worth checking out http://www.oreilly.com/openbook/samba/book/ch05_03.html and experimenting with various settings. Other than that, sorry... can' help further.